# Why does using ? on Result<_, &str> cause a lifetime error?

Tags: rust, lifetime

I have this code that doesn't compile:

```rust
impl BytePacketBuffer {
    fn read(&mut self) -> Result<u8, &str> {
        if self.pos >= 512 {
            return Err("End of buffer".into());
        }
        let res = self.buf[self.pos];
        self.pos += 1;

        Ok(res)
    }

    fn read_u16(&mut self) -> Result<u16, &str> {
        let res = ((self.read()? as u16) << 8) | (self.read()? as u16);
        Ok(res)
    }
}
```

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `*self` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/byte_packet_buffer.rs:53:51
   |
52 |     fn read_u16(&mut self) -> Result<u16, &str> {
   |                 - let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`
53 |         let res = ((self.read()? as u16) << 8) | (self.read()? as u16);
   |                     ------------                  ^^^^^^^^^^^ second mutable borrow occurs here
   |                     |
   |                     first mutable borrow occurs here
   |                     returning this value requires that `*self` is borrowed for `'1`
```

But if I modify the return type from `&str` to `String`, it compiles without error. Can anybody explain why I get an error when returning `&str` but not when returning `String`?

Comment: Hmm... An interesting case. I have the feeling that this is NLL case #3 with `?` desugaring. Let's test with Polonius... Yep. It works with Polonius.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you did not specify any lifetimes Rust will infer them according to the [elision rules](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/lifetime-elision.html) to be this:

```rust
fn read<'a>(&'a mut self) -> Result<u8, &'a str>
```

which means it will infer `self` to be borrowed for as long as you keep the `Result` or anything it contained around.
To fix it you could just specify the lifetime of the returned `str` because it's always static anyways.

```rust
fn read(&mut self) -> Result<u8, &'static str>
```

Comment: This "fixes" the symptom but doesn't explain what is really going on. In fact, Rust is being overly restrictive and this example should really be allowed.

Comment: @PeterHall How did I not explain what's going on? Because of omitted lifetimes rust infers them, this being based on simplistic rules leads to wrong assumptions, fix it by providing correct lifetimes.

Comment: No, because `'static` is more restrictive than this needs to be. It rules out valid usages where the `&str` in the error is borrowed from `self`.

Answer (score 3):

@cafce25 explained well how lifetime elision leads to incorrect lifetime, but this still does not explain why this fails. Even with the incorrect lifetimes, when we borrow `self` for the `&str` it is the error case, and the error case is immediately returning from the function and thus does not borrow `self` further.

Well, this is because the `?` operators desugars roughly into (simplified, but the actual desugaring doesn't matter here):

```rust
match expr {
    Ok(v) => v,
    Err(e) => return Err(From::from(e)),
}
```

And [it is well known that the borrow checker is overly conservative w.r.t. branches](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/54663). It extends borrow in return expression to the rest of the function, causing the `&str` to live even when it cannot really live.

If you compile it with [Polonius](https://github.com/rust-lang/polonius) (`cargo +nightly rustc -- -Zpolonius`), it compiles successfully.